# Excel Count ifs with arrays and multiple criteria's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, countif

I have to use multiple arrays as i multiple criteria's, it is not working for me. I have tried both sum and sumproduct and also Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Below is my formula

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(stage,$E2,report_date,F$1,active,IF($B$6="(All)","\<\>"&0,$B$6),region,$Q$1:$Q$11,program,$R$1:$R$11,family,$P$1:$P$11,status,$S$1:$S$11))
```

Also i tried to name all ranges

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(stage,$E2,report_date,F$1,active,IF($B$6="(All)","\<\>"&0,$B$6),region,region1,program,program1,family,Family1,status,status1))
```

Also i tried all references

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(stage,$E2,report_date,F$1,active,IF($B$6="(All)","\<\>"&0,$B$6),region,C2,program,C1,family,C5,status,C3))
```

non of the above are working for me.

Can anyone help me out.

Basically i am creating a dynamic table matching to a particular pivot. I have to display all data in tabular format with historical comparison.

Comment: With the `IFS` family of functions, it is not possible to apply more than two sets of (orthogonal) array criteria when wishing to obtain a count over all permutations from those arrays. In such cases you need to switch to, for example, `SUMPRODUCT` or `FILTER`.

Comment: Could you post a data example and your expected output?

Comment: Switch to `SUMPRODUCT` and convert your statements to the form `N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MyRange,MyCriteriaRange,0)))`.

Comment: if i use n(isnumber(Match) it is showing only unique number. I want the total count

Comment: how can i use sumproduct with multiple criteria's. with filter i could do only one criteria

Comment: As @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Sir, has mentioned, could you please share a MOCK Data with the expected output, that shall will be more transparent provided then experts can offer you a solution more appropriately

Comment: Sure i will do it in sometime. i have my limitations to share the organisation data outside.

Comment: Hi, how can i share sample file?